# How to change the structure of an an XML

Tags: python, xml, lxml

From this string:

```
label_config={
    "label1": [
        "modality1",
        "modality2",
        "modality3"],
    "choice":"single",
    "required": "true",
    "name" : "sentiment"},{
    "label2": [
        "modality1",
        "modality2"],
    "name" : "price"
 }
```

I created this XML which is printed:

[image]

Anyone knows how thanks to this library: from lxml import etree
can move the slashes of the yellow elements from the end to the beginning?

Here is the code of the generation:

```
from lxml import etree
import sys

def topXML(dictAttrib = None):
    root : {lxml.etree._Element}
    root = etree.Element("View")
    textEl = etree.SubElement(root, "Text")
    if dictAttrib == None:
        dictAttrib = {
            "name":"text",
            "value":"$text"
        }
        for k_,v_ in dictAttrib.items():
            textEl.set(k_,v_)
            
    return root

def choiceXML(root,locChoice):

    headerEl = etree.SubElement(root, "Header")
    choisesEl = etree.SubElement(root, "Choices")
    for k_,v_ in locChoice.items():
        if (isinstance(k_,str) & isinstance(v_,list)):
            choices = v_
            headerEl.set("value",k_)
            if locChoice.get("toName") == None:
                choisesEl.set("toName","text")
            for op_ in choices:
                opEl = etree.SubElement(root, "Choice")
                opEl.set("value",op_)
        else :
            choisesEl.set(k_,v_)
    choisesEl = etree.SubElement(root, "Choices")
    
    return root

def checkConfig(locChoice):

    if locChoice.get("name") == None : 
        sys.exit("Warning : label_config needs a parameter called 'name' assigned")

def xmlConstructor(label_config):

    root = topXML()
    for ch_ in label_config:
        checkConfig(ch_)
        root = choiceXML(root,ch_)
    return root
```

The generated code will be used in this site https://labelstud.io/playground/. They use some type of XML do create the code. Unfortunately, using etree it doesn't achieve the wanted product and I found out that if I made the changes described above it will work.

In the meantime, I am contacting their team to get more info but if somoeone here has any idea on how to make it work, please come forward.

Comment: What you are asking will create a not well-formed XML.

Comment: I know, unfortunately  it will be temporary due to a problem with another library. It will take 6 months for the other change, so meanwhile this is the only solution

Comment: Don't you want XML where the `Choice` elements are children of `Choices`? Btw, please don't post XML (or code) as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To correctly encapsulate the `<Choice>` nodes under its parent, `<Choices>`, simply make the following very simple two changes to your `choiceXML` method. Namely, add `opEl` sub elements under the `choisesEl` element (not `root`) and remove the redundant second `choisesEl` line at the end.

```py
def choiceXML(root, locChoice):
    headerEl = etree.SubElement(root, "Header")
    choisesEl = etree.SubElement(root, "Choices")
    for k_,v_ in locChoice.items():
        if (isinstance(k_,str) & isinstance(v_,list)):
            choices = v_
            headerEl.set("value",k_)
            if locChoice.get("toName") == None:
                choisesEl.set("toName","text")
            for op_ in choices:
                opEl = etree.SubElement(choisesEl, "Choice")     # CHANGE root to choisesEl
                opEl.set("value",op_)
        else :
            choisesEl.set(k_,v_)
    #choisesEl = etree.SubElement(root, "Choices")               # REMOVE THIS LINE

    return root
```

**Full Process**

```py
label_config = {
    "label1": [
        "modality1",
        "modality2",
        "modality3"],
    "choice":"single",
    "required": "true",
    "name" : "sentiment"},{
    "label2": [
        "modality1",
        "modality2"],
    "name" : "price"
 }

def topXML(dictAttrib = None):
    # ...NO CHANGE...

def choiceXML(root,locChoice):
    # ...ABOVE CHANGE...

def checkConfig(locChoice):
    # ...NO CHANGE...

def xmlConstructor(label_config):
    # ...NO CHANGE...

output = xmlConstructor(label_config)
```

**Output**

```py
print(etree.tostring(output, pretty_print=True).decode("utf-8"))

# <View>
#   <Text name="text" value="$text"/>
#   <Header value="label1"/>
#   <Choices toName="text" choice="single" required="true" name="sentiment">
#     <Choice value="modality1"/>
#     <Choice value="modality2"/>
#     <Choice value="modality3"/>
#   </Choices>
#   <Header value="label2"/>
#   <Choices toName="text" name="price">
#     <Choice value="modality1"/>
#     <Choice value="modality2"/>
#   </Choices>
# </View>
```

Comment: Merci beacoup. Great answear, I solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

The `<Choices/>` is short for `<Choices></Choices>` ([XML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#d0e2480)). If you just make it a closing element, you probably don't have an opening one, and the result will be invalid xml. Any program trying to read / parse that will error out.

Notice that you have trailing slashes on all your `<Choices>` elements, also the non-empty ones.

If you don't want the empty `<Choices/>` elements, you may need to look into how you generate the XML from the dict. Since you don't provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) we can't answer that part.

Comment: I just provided the code. You can take a look at. Normally the end product should fit in label-studio

Answer (score -1):

This is more a comment than an answer, but it's a bit too long for a comment. Looking at what you provide, it seems like the problem is not that your xml is too well formed (there's no such thing) or that the playground has some sort of weird xml structure. I believe the xml you generated is not what they are looking for.

If you look at your 2nd `<Choices>` element, it reads

```
<Choices toName="text" name="price"/>
```

Try dropping the closing `/` so it reads:

```
<Choices toName="text" name="price">
```

It will then be closed with the following `<Choices/>` and maybe it will work.